# Prove $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, diffeomorphism

Let $d \in \mathbb N$.

Define $\Phi:]0, \infty[ \times \{ x \in \mathbb R^{d-1}: |x|<1\}\to \{y \in \mathbb R^d:y_{1}>0\}, (r,x) \mapsto r(\sqrt{1-|x|^2},x)$

Show that $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism.

**Ideas:**

$1.$ Bijectivity:

$1.1$ Injectivity:
Let $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$ and $r,s \in ]0, \infty[$ whereby $x \neq y$ or $r \neq s$

if $x \neq y$ is clear that $\Phi(r,x)\neq \Phi(r,y)\Rightarrow$ injectivity

So let $s \neq r$ and  $\Phi(s,x)=s(\sqrt{1-|x|^2},x) \neq\Phi(r,x)=r(\sqrt{1-|x|^2},x) \Rightarrow$ injectivity

$1.2$ Surjectivity: Let $z \in \{y \in \mathbb R^d:y_{1}>0\}$ it is clear that there is an $r \in ]0, \infty[$ so that $r \sqrt{1-|x|^2}=z_{1}\Rightarrow$ surjectivity

$\Rightarrow$ Bijectivity

On the issue of Differentiability of $\Phi$ as well as Differentiability $\Phi^{-1}$ I am lost, as this is the first time doing this...

Any ideas, corrections, tips?

Comment: Your injectivity proof does not work. You also have to consider $r\neq s$ and $x\neq y$ while $\Phi(r,x)= \Phi(s,y)$. For the differentability you can use the fact that a function is differentiable iff each coordinate is differentiable. An easy way to check differentiabilty of the inverse function is to use the inverse function theorem. Otherwise you have to find the inverse and check by hand that it is differentiable.

Comment: So $\Phi$ is not injective?

Comment: It is, but your proof is not complete.

Comment: Also your proof of surjectivity is not clear at all. If you change $r$, you also change the second coordinate.

Comment: On the issue of injectivity where $ r \neq s$ and $x \neq y$ do you mean we generate a contradiction after assuming $\Phi(r,x) = \Phi(s,y)$? Because assuming $r(\sqrt{1-|x|^2},x)=s(\sqrt{1-|y|^2},y)$ that would mean $r(\sqrt{1-|x|^2})=s(\sqrt{1-|y|^2})$ and that $rx_{i}=sy_{i}, \forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$. I have no idea how to generate a contradiction from this

Comment: You want to start with $\Phi(r,x)=\Phi(s,y)$. Then you get $\vert x \vert=\frac{s}{r}\vert y \vert$. Plug this into $r\sqrt{1-\vert x\vert^2} = s \sqrt{1-\vert y \vert^2}$. After some computations you will get $\left( \frac{r}{s} \right)^2=1$ from which you can deduce (after some observation) that $r=s$. Then you get $x = \frac{r}{s} y=y$. Hence, $(r,x)= (s,y)$.

Comment: One computes that for $(r,x)$ in our domain we have $$ det(D\Phi(r,x)) = \sqrt{1-\vert x \vert^2 } r^{d-1} + r \frac{x_1^2}{\sqrt{1-\vert x \vert^2}} r^{d-2} = \frac{r^{d-1}}{\sqrt{1-\vert x \vert^2}} (1- \vert x \vert^2 + x_1^2)>  \frac{r^{d-1} x_1^2}{\sqrt{1-\vert x \vert^2}}\geq 0 . $$ This means the differential of our function is invertible and hence, by the inverse function theorem, we know that our function is a local diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The easiest way is to find the inverse function. For this we compute
$$ \vert \Phi(r,x) \vert = r $$
as
$$ \vert \Phi(r,x) \vert = \vert r \vert \sqrt{(1-\vert x \vert^2)+ x_1^2 + \dots + x_{d_1}^2} = \vert r \vert \sqrt{1- \vert x \vert^2 + \vert x \vert^2} = \vert r \vert = r. $$
Hence, the inverse function is (for $y=(y_1, \dots, y_d)$)
$$ \Psi (y_1, \dots, y_d) = \left(\vert y \vert, \frac{1}{\vert y \vert} y_2, \dots, \frac{1}{\vert y \vert} y_d \right).$$